# How to query child nodes in parent node entity of neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

For example, I have an entity like this:

```
@Data
@NodeEntity(label = "Subject")
public class Subject {
     @GraphId
     private Long id;
     private String name;

     @Relationship(type = "HAVE_S", direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
     private Set<Subject> children = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Then I need to query a 'Subject' by graphId;

```
@Query("MATCH (s:Subject)-[r:HAVE_S*1]->(c:Subject) WHERE ID(s) = {graphId} RETURN s, r, c;")
Subject findById(@Param("graphId") Long graphId);
```

The result I want just like the following json:

```
{
    "id": 62
    "name": "Java"
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Collection",
            "id": 105
        },
        {
            "name": "MultipleThreads",
            "id": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

But when I executed the cypher above through Spring Data,  an error comes out and says "Result not of expected size. Expected 1 row but found 3".

I hope someone can help me with this problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As your model suggests A subject have multiple children so when you are fetching it by id it's returning a cartesian product of your subject* children. In this case you need to collect your children(subjects and then return)

```
@Query("MATCH (s:Subject)-[r:HAVE_S*1]->(c:Subject) WHERE ID(s) = {graphId} RETURN s,  collect(c) as childrens;")
```

or simply you can use findById() of your repository the SDN will create query by itself

Comment: I used your cypher query but I still got the same error. Then I tried findOne() method provided by Spring Data, it returns all nodes but no relations

Comment: Like `{
    "id": 62
    "name": "Java"
    "children": []
}`

Comment: 1 in findOne() , there is depth property Please set that to 1.
2: in the above custom query try annotation @queryresult at the above class also try the above query in cypher terminal.

Comment: It works only on 1 depth, the subject has multiple layers, like Java->Collection->Map, I need the result like { "id": 62, "name": "Java" "children": [{"id": 105, "name": "Collection" "children": [ { "id": 0, "name": "Map" "children":[] } ] } ] }

Comment: surely if you need infinite then try binding the result in an object class or map for a try and check what's the difference between your expected result and the actual result.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this.

```
MATCH (k:LabelsTree {name:'465afe3c118589de357745a709c0441f'}) CALL apoc.path.spanningTree(k,{labelFilter:'+LabelsTree', maxLevel:3, optional:true, filterStartNode:true}) yield path return path
```

[Refer to the connection](http://we-yun.com/apoc/index34.html#_path_expander)